# MongoDB Multiply Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I have a projection like this:

```
{ "$project": {
        "answer": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$up", 0 ] },
                0,
                { "$divide": [ "$up", "$total_count" ] }
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$sort" : {
        "_id": 1
    }}
```

Right now, the result of `{ "$divide": [ "$up", "$total_count" ] }` is a decimal (e.g. `.75`).

How do I multiply this result by 100 (to get `75`)?

In other words, where should I put the `$multiply`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to pass in the `{ "$divide": [ "$up", "$total_count" ] }` as an element of an array to `$multiply` with the other element of that array being the constant you want to multiply by. Try this:

```
{ $multiply : [{"$divide": [ "$up", "$total_count" ]}, 100] }
```

Just to note - it helps if you post a couple of sample docs for aggregation questions like this so that we can test the results before replying, otherwise we have to reverse engineer the document to be 100% sure.